# Monitoring Memcached with PHP script

Tags: php, memcached, monitoring

I've written a PHP script that I've scheduled with CRON to run every minute. The goal of the script is to verify that the memcached server is online. My strategy is simply to attempt to connect to the memcached server. If I connect successfully, I close the connection. If I do not successfully connect, I send an email alerting that memcached is offline.

My question: is this a sufficient test that memcached is up and running, or is it common practice to do more than just connect to memcached? Should I also test that I can set and retrieve a key/value pair?

Also, in the future, we may want to do more extensive monitoring of memcached so we can track memory usage, connections, number of requests, etc. Are there open source libraries for doing this from PHP? If so, which ones have performed nicely in your experience?

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to build anything. There are a number of PHP scripts intended for monitoring, debugging and displaying stats for a Memchached server.

There are two that I know of and work well:

- phpmemcacheadmin [full monitoring and debugging suite](http://code.google.com/p/phpmemcacheadmin/)
- memcache.php [simple script sort of like apc.php](http://pecl.php.net/package/memcache) (bundled in the archive file for a release)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm trying to determine if either of these tools will provide a script which I can schedule to run at an interval like once per minute and email me to alert if memcached is not running. At a quick glance, I'm not confident they do.

Comment: The script to ping the server and request a key every minute should be very simple to do. Just use one of the scripts above for debugging and monitoring because that is were it becomes difficult.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a shot and let you know if I find anything interesting or noteworthy as a follow up to this question.

Comment: The Link to memcache.php is broken. However, it is always included in the released archive files on http://pecl.php.net/package/memcache